# hadoop get 'No such file or directory'

Tags: python, python-2.7, hadoop

I'm using multi-process in `python 2.7`, and I need to get a file from `HDFS` by using the command `hadoop fs -get`.

But when execute

```
os.system('hadoop fs -get hdfs_file local_file')
```

in python code, the multi-process will occur conflict, some of the process will print the error:

```
'get: No such file or directory'
```

and some of the process will print

```
'get: File local_file._COPYING_ does not exist'
```

If I read this in the latter python code, I will read an empty file.

Is there any solutions to deal with this problem? Or what should I do to get `HDFS` file if the multi-process architecture is unremovable?

Answer (score 0):

Run below code on your command prompt:

```
hadoop fs -ls /hdfs_file local_file
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to attach some prefix to `local_file`, e.g. `str(int(time.time()*1000000)) + local_file`

`_COPYING_` is a staging file during downloading. If you used the same `local_file` name to download in a multi-process job, some process finished earlier therefore `local_file._COPYING_` was deleted. As a result, other processes that run a little bit slower would find `local_file._COPYING_` doesn't exist.